# Can I attack a World Boss, leave the area and still get a reward?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I've noticed that sometime I participate to an event (protect a random NPC, helping kill Centaurs/Ogres, etc.) but *not on purpose*. By *not on purpose* I mean that I simply crossed path with this event on my way to somewhere else and barely participate in it (e.g. Just threw an attack). However no matter how far I go from the event's zone I still recieve the Gold/Karma/XP.

Is it the same with World's Boss that leave a chest of loot after death ? Can I simply come > hit the Boss once > leave the area and still come back to a chest of loot ?

Comment: You can go as far as you want **without leaving the map instance** and still receive event credit, but if you leave the instance of the map in which you contributed to the event, you will not receive credit. World bosses are no different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope, afraid not. You need to stay in the area (map) to get credit for any events.

Events remember who participated, even a little (e.g. a single hit - one that does damage, that is - on an event-related NPC or target, or handing a single item to the collector NPC for collection events) and will reward you with at least bronze-level participation *as long as you stay in the area instance**.

Let's say there's an event in Gendarran Fields - if you leave that area, whether that's by going to WvW or PvP, or you walk or waypoint out, you won't get credit. Distance doesn't matter, just being in that area until the event finishes.

This goes for World Events as well as Group Events and normal events. If, as you say, you received credit (gold/karma/XP) for an event that you only did a little for, I'm sure you must have remained in the area.

Even going to another instance of the *same* map counts as leaving it, e.g. by right-clicking on a party member who's in another instance and doing "Join in (area name)".

---

*As pointed out by Vael Victus in the comments, note that getting credit for (bronze) event participation (gold/karma/XP for *any* contribution) is not always the same as getting *enough* credit to earn the additional chests, for which you may need more than a token one-hit contribution.

Comment: But, on a side note... the first ascended chest that ever dropped for me was when I ran with all the speedboosts available to me to get to the Jormag event in Frostgorge with just enough time to launch a single (though multi-hit) ranged attack before it finished. Gotta love (and hate) RNG-based rewards... :-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I appear to have been lucky aswell since my first black lion chest contained a ticket that allowed me to purchase a skin sold for 60 gold :).

Comment: A related side note: some events require you to achieve over bronze level for the reward. I learned that as I lazily played my thief in the post-event after killing Risen Priest of Melandru; no chest for me.

Comment: @VaelVictus: Good point, thanks - note added to the answer.